# Json RPC list methods

Tags: java, python, json, rpc

is there any possibility of getting all available methods from a JSON-RPC server? The server I am connecting to isn't that well documented, so I had to guess a lot of the method names.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean... If by "methods" you mean RMIs, is this helpful? https://vtk.org/Wiki/JSON-RPC_Protocol#Obtaining_list_of_available_RMIs